# How to set up Monitoring for queue in activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, monitoring, jmx

I read in ActiveMQ page, using JMX we can monitor queues in activemq. How can we get notified if a queue has messages (depth high) or service interval is high in ActiveMQ. Without using any shell scripts in unix environment. Is it possible through Java program? If yes, give me some ideas to get this done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a JMX-free approach, you can also use the XML feed served by the activemq console page. The XML feed is hosted at `http://ip:port/admin/xml/queues.jsp`

This will have tags similar to this for each queue:

```
<queue name="your queue">
<stats size="0" consumerCount="1" enqueueCount="0" dequeueCount="0"/>
....
</queue>
```

Just parse this XML in your code and you are good to go.

Answer (score 6):

you can use Java via [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) APIs to periodically poll for queue stats (see [this guide](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html))

for the notification approach, you'd need to use [advisory messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) to monitor messages delivered to a queue (see [this guide](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/handling-advisory-messages.html))

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible in Java.

Starting from version 5.8 of ActiveMQ jolokia agent comes embedded. So it is possible for you to get all stats that JMX can pull using HTTP request which will retuen you stats as JSON and then you can check current values and raise Email alert using SMTP if values go beyond threshold you have decided.

Lets say you want to pull Broker stats using Jolokia hit below URL in your browser enter AMQ console username and password which is admin by default
http://servername.com:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost

Or if you dont want to go through all this trouble , You can use ready made Python script which I have created to Monitor AMQ Heap, Queue params and Broker availability.You can take a look , it may help you in developing your custiom script or program

[AMQMonitor and Alerting script](https://gist.github.com/Abhinav2510/f11507501463257d96732290dc72bf51)